# is it possible to edit an entry from the front-end when you're not logged in?

Tags: entries, entry, guest-entries

I'm working on a checkout process for a takeaway restaurant where anonymous visitors can place orders using guest entries.

In this stage the order is saved with a status of "unpaid". Once a visitor saves the order he's taken to a payment provider service where he pays for his order, once the order is payed the visitor is redirected to a page where the order status would be set to "paid" in a hidden form.

In order to accomplish this the aforementioned saved guest entry would have to be edited from the front-end. Is it possible to anonymously edit an entry?

Comment: You may need to provide us with more details. i.e. Does the guest user submit a form? What action should trigger the update? What specifically are you trying to update? etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to edit that entry using `craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)` with `$entry->authorId` set to a registered user with the necessary permissions. To get the ID of the user that created the entry, access the Guest Entries plugin settings in your plugin:

```
$settings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('guestentries')->getSettings();
$authorId = $settings->defaultAuthors[$entry->section->handle];
```